# Everytime a page is refreshed i lose data, but i want to keep the last textbox value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i was working on a program that i wrote in php, all is fine, the problem is the html page:
it has 1 textbox and 1 button. 
In the textbox i have to write a link

when i load the page it clicks the button automatically, so i can use the php program, then it return back to the html page..

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('#printbuttoncustomer').trigger('click');});
```

The links that i need to use are always the same, except the number, example:
http://www.wowhead.com/npc=56843 --- http://www.wowhead.com/npc=56844 etc..

the problem is that everytime the page is loaded, it start to use always the link and can't go on with the next link with the new value
how can i solve this problem?

I think that i could use a txt file to save the last link i used, so in the html i can check the last link in the txt file and set the next value in the textbox.. But don't know how to do.

the code to start is this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <form method="POST" action="parser.php">
<input type="text" id="testo" name="testo">
<input type="submit" id="button" >
</form>


    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#button').trigger('click');
            });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the html page to php. When returning to this page from "parser.php", send back a response with next link and save that in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the link in a session and not a file :

```
$_SESSION['URL'] = "Your URL HERE"
```

next time you read it like this:

```
var $MyUrl = $_SESSION['URL'];
```

Please check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) for more on PHP Sessions.

Comment: i didn't understand very well..$_SESSION['URL'] = "Your URL HERE", it should be the next url or the url that i used to go to parser.php page? and the session code have to be write in the html page (that will be trasnformed into a php page) or in parser.php?

Comment: Your question states that you want to keep the last textBox Value. So save that value in a session and read it the next time you load your page.Keep in mind that Session's lifetime is as long as your browser is open. If you want to keep the link even after you close your browser, you need to save the link in a Cookie.

Comment: @user3187101 The $_SESSION['URL'] = "Your URL HERE" goes in the parser.php and "Your URL HERE" means the last link. var $MyUrl = $_SESSION['URL']; goes to the html page (which you will have to convert to php to use this code) to check the last link and use it somehow to create new link and store in text field

Comment: parser.php --> $link = $_POST['testo'];
    $_SESSION['URL'] = $link;                 now i go on page.php: <?php $MyUrl = $_SESSION['URL'];    if($MyUrl == $link) { newLinkCalculationCode} ?> <html> etc.... is it right?

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP syntax , but it seems that the logic is correct. Give it a try.

Comment: is the last link needs to be secure? Is it a private information or is it something anyone can get? If its the latter use JS cookies, otherwise PHP sessions it is.

Comment: no this is a tool that have to be used only by me, i want to retrieve some information from the html page of wowhead, with parser.php, with the page.php (ex page.html) i will type in the textbox the link and automatically the page have to change the numeric part of the link and go to the php page to parse everything, then from parser.php return to page.php, rewrite the new number in the link, all this in loop

Comment: ok guys, i really don't know what to do, i tried but no results, give a look http://www.mediafire.com/download/wosyilx4sdvarwd/parser.rar

Comment: @user3187101 In your code grabber.php, you have used $_SESSION. But for the first time when the page loads, the $_SESSION['URL'] will be NULL. So you have to check for that, and set the initial value for $nuovoindirizzo that will be used for the first time when the page loads.Also $indirizzo is not defined. And $nuovoindirizzo should be defined outside of 'if' block, otherwise it won't be accessible outside of if block.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to persist the information of your last clicked page so that next time you load the page it goes to next page.

You can do this by two ways:-

*Server Side Change:-

You can implement sessions to store the information, where you store the last URL.

*Client Side Change:-

After HTML5 there are a lot of browser storage is available. So you can use local storage, it stores site specific data in browsers persistent memory. Also there is session storage available.[Check this page for HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_storage.htm).